# Integration of a differential equation

Tags: integration, analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

I've got some problems with integrating a ODE, so maybe someone could add some words of advice.

Given the following equation:
$z''(x)-2\gamma z'(x) +p(x)z(x)=0$, $(1)$

and $\varphi(x)=z(x)e^{-\gamma x}$  $(2)$

, where $\gamma$ is a complex constant and $p(x),z(x),\varphi(x)$ are real funcions working on $\mathbb{R}$.
In addition it is assumed that $z'(x)\rightarrow 0 ; z(x)\rightarrow 1$ for $x\rightarrow \infty$. $(3)$

Now I want to show $z'(x)=\int_x^\infty e^{2\gamma(x-s)}p(s)z(s)ds$

I started rearranging $(1)$ to: $z''(x)=2\gamma z'(x)-p(x)z(x)$
Integrating both sides of $(1)$ from $x$ to $\infty$ yields 
$\int_x^\infty z''(s)ds=z'(\infty)-z'(x)=0-z'(x)=\int_x^\infty 2\gamma z'(s)-p(s)z(s)ds$ because of $(3)$

But now I don't know how to go on, because I don't see how to reach with forming the integral on the right side, that there will be the $e^{\cdots}$ term. Even when I will use the assumption $(2)$ I'll some $\varphi(x)$ too. So I guess one have to integrate in a clever way or need something else to know. Maybe someone could point me in the right direction.

By the way: I've got also problems with $x$ in the integral and the $x$ in $e^{2\gamma(x-s)}$. I tried to derive both sides with respect to $x$ for getting an idea how to solve the problem why there is the $e$ term. But unfortunately  I'm quite unsure with deriving in these special situation.

Thanks!

Comment: Multiply your equation by $\exp(-2\gamma x)$. Your equation is now $$(z^{\prime}\exp(-2\gamma x))^{\prime}=-p(x)\exp(-2\gamma x)z(x)$$ and integration from $x$ to $\infty$ give the result.

Comment: My method works if $z^{\prime}(x)\exp(-2\gamma x)\to 0$ if $x\to +\infty$; Is it the case ?

Comment: @Kelenner Thank you for answering. It's a quite promising way of solution. By the fact that $z(x)$ is assumed to be sufficiently continuous and the assumption that $z'(x)\rightarrow 0$ for $x\rightarrow\infty$ I would say that it's clear, isn't it?